# Why this java statement is generating this output?

Tags: java, concatenation

I have a string str, let's say it's value is "hell".

The below statement returns "205hellhe" instead of "hehellhe"

```
return (str.charAt(0)) + (str.charAt(1))+str+(str.charAt(0)) + (str.charAt(1));
```

why (str.charAt(0)) + (str.charAt(1)) is returning 205 instead of "he" and why the same statement is returning "he" at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Expressions are evaluated Left-To-Right.
- Hence first two chars are evaluated and added, which results in a char (value = 205).
- Next this char(=205) is added to a string, which results in String.

Hence the strange output.

Fix:

Use a `StringBuilder` instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "hell";
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
    buff.append(str.charAt(0))
            .append(str.charAt(1))
            .append(str)
            .append(str.charAt(0))
            .append(str.charAt(1));
    System.out.println(buff.toString());// prints 'hehellhe'
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use StringBuilder here. Better solution is to create an empty string and then repeatedly use operator "+=" with each item. It'll be much faster and code will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the values of the ASCII codes of the characters are being added instead of being concatenated. In ASCII, **h** is represented as 104, and **e** as 101. The concatenation isn't working, probably because both operands in this case are chars/integers.